# Why I can only train some NetModel with GPU

Tags: neural-networks, gpu

I can train NetModel's models with CPU.
I'm on Windows 10 with Mathematica 11.2 GPU is GTX1080 with 8G memory.

My datasets is 1000 pictures with 224*224.

I can train some NetModel like `Inception V1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data` with TargetDevice->"GPU"

But I cannot train some NetModel like `ResNet-152 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data` with TargetDevice->"GPU"

```
NetTrain::interr: An internal error occurred. Please contact Wolfram Research.
```

Since I can train some model with GPU, I think my graphics card driver is OK.
Since I can train them with CPU, I think Mathematica implement their layers.

I can use ImageRestyle with TargetDevice->"GPU", if I encounter with the problem `An internal error occurred` in training NetModel, then ImageRestyle also gives the same error information unless I Quit or Restart Mathematica.

---

I can train with GPU:

"Inception V1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"

"Wolfram ImageIdentify Net for WL 11.1"

"Yahoo Open NSFW Model V1"

"SqueezeNet V1.1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data" crashes my kernel like Quit.

---

Well, some net can be trained with 20/30 pictures, but some can be trained by 1000 pictures....I'm not sure whether this is normal?

Even I use File object, the Out of Core training, it also gives the error information, and has limit number of training set.

Comment: Could you post the output of: ``Internal`$LastInternalFailure`` and ``Internal`$LastUncaughtFailure``? I'm pretty sure the problem is that your GPU is running out of memory, and this is not being reported correctly.

Comment: @Sebastian wow, yes, your're right.  `MXNetError
[19:32:16] : cudaMalloc failed: out of memory`, I overrate the ability of GTX1080, my datasets is 1000 pictures. But the problem is even 
I use only 100 pictures, it alslo gives the error...

Comment: @Sebastian I can train `ResNet-152` with 30 pictures.

Comment: 1000 images should be fine: its not loading them all into GPU memory. Can you try `BatchSize -> 32` in `NetTrain`? Does it work now on the full dataset?

Comment: @Sebastian It's OK, thank you, I think you can post an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cause is the GPU running out of memory, and Mathematica not correctly reporting the failure (ResNet 152 is very memory hungry!).

This can be seen by running `` Internal`$LastInternalFailure ``, which will include a line "cudaMalloc failed: out of memory". I have reported this incorrect reporting as a bug.

Try a smaller `BatchSize` in `NetTrain` to reduce your memory usage in order to train a large net like this.